# Linearizing cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to understand the geometric interpretation of KKT conditions for nonlinear programs.

Consider the following nonlinear program:
$$\min\ f(x)$$
$$s.t.\ g_i(x)\leq 0,\ i=1,...,m$$
$$h_j(x)=0,\ j=1,...,n$$

$\textbf{Definition}$. For a feasible point $x$, the linearizing cone is defined as
$$L(x)=\{d| \langle \nabla g_i(x),d \rangle \leq 0,(i,g_i(x)=0),\ \langle \nabla h_j(x),d \rangle = 0, \forall j \}$$.

$\textbf{Question}$. What is the significance of this cone? why is it called linearizing? and why does it contain all the tangent cone at $x$?

Comment: it's called linearizing because it  is a polyhedral cone  where locally approximating feasible set around the feasible point $x$.

For your second question take $d$ in tangent cone then there exist positive  sequence $t_n$ such that $t_n \to 0 $ and $x+t_n d \in$ Feasible Set. Now directional derivative at $x$ in direction $d$ gives you the result  .

Comment: @Redshoes Could you please elaborate on "locally approximating feasible set around the feasible point x"? I don't understand how one can linearly approximate a set of inequalities/equalities.